# Memgraph v2.12.1 Fails to Start on Ubuntu 22.04.2 that runs in WSL

Tags: memgraphdb

I have a clean Windows 11 Pro machine with all of the updated. I've installed WSL with Ubuntu using PowerShell.

In terminal I've downloaded and installed Memgraph:

```
wget https://download.memgraph.com/memgraph/v2.12.1/ubuntu-22.04/memgraph_2.12.1-1_amd64.deb 
sudo dpkg -i memgraph_2.12.1-1_amd64.deb 
sudo runuser -l memgraph -c '/usr/lib/memgraph/memgraph'
```

I get the error:

```
You are running Memgraph v2.12.1
To get started with Memgraph, visit https://memgr.ph/start
Aborted
```

I've restated the computer and I tried to run `sudo runuser -l memgraph -c '/usr/lib/memgraph/memgraph'`  again.

This time I got:

```
You are running Memgraph v2.12.1
To get started with Memgraph, visit https://memgr.ph/start
Max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count 65530 is too low, increase to at least 262144
Aborted
```

My log files shows:

```
Assertion failed in file /memgraph/src/memgraph.cpp at line 239.
        Expression: 'lock_file_handle.AcquireLock()'
        Message: 'Couldn't acquire lock on the storage directory "/var/lib/memgraph"!
Another Memgraph process is currently running with the same storage directory, please stop it first before starting this process!'
```

What am I doing wrong?